# The uses of prepositions

Tags: prepositions

I know prepositions can be very confusing, at least for Spanih speakers. For example: The uses of "in" and "on"
We normally use "in" to say: "IN the morning"  or  "he is swimming IN the river" It makes perfect tense to me,  but why is it also correct to say:  "ON the morning of June 24".

The same happens with the preposition "on". I understand if one says: The boat is ON the river" But why is it also correct to say: "Theme park floating IN the Atlantic Ocean." Can you help?

Comment: We  can't tell you every single thing about prepositions. We say swimming in the river,also. This is a case-by-case basis in terms of differences with Spanish. You have several questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The bottle was floating **in the ocean**. [part of it is sticking up, part isn't]
- The plastic bag was floating on the water.
- The bottle was floating **on the ocean**. [means the surface of the water, no part sticking down]
- The plastic bag was floating **in the water**. [partially submerged or not all on the surface]

**The theme park is on the surface of the water** but **part of it is submerged**. Therefore, floating **in the ocean** is fine. One could also say **on** here. It depends on how you look at it in this particular case. With the ocean, it depends on the level of submersion.

The body was found floating in the ocean. [not on: part of it is submerged]

Please note: He was in the house. [inside]. He was on the house. [roof, a surface]

"In the morning" is not the same as a date.

**On the morning of July 15** = **because of the date**.

**On July 15, On the afternoon of July 15**.

Then, there are times where you get this in Spanish in response to a question: en absoluto and it means: absolutely not. So, en as on is not always so clear.

I have tried to answer your questions specifically, not write a treatise on prepositions. :)